# Access to EKevent and EKReminder

Tags: events, eventkit, ios7.1, reminders, ekeventstore

In my iOS calendar app When Request privacy from EKEventstore For Event all thing done well.But when allow app to access Reminders All calendar disappear and when try to get calendars nil returned.

This issue in iOS 7.1 only.
Steps to produced:
1-Reset all Privacy from settings.
2-Run calendar app.
3-Request Privacy to access Events.
4-get calendar from store work correctly.
5-Request Privacy to Access Reminders.
6-Kill app and reopen it.
6-get calendar doesn't work correctly and return nil.

Anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check how many calendars and reminders list you have, if they are more than 100, then the event store will stop working correctly. 
For more information check this from apple: [iCloud: Limits for Contacts, Calendars, Reminders, and Bookmarks](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4489?viewlocale=en_US)